# Authenticate the Test User { "error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app" }

Tags: instagram-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to recover the access token via the Instagram Basic Display API but when trying to authenticate the test user I get this error:

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid platform app"
}
```

I expect to see the app authorization screen

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution for this? I’m having the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Felice! I have the same problem. Would you like to help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Felice!

When setting up an Instagram app, you should use the platform-specific App ID and not the generic one set up on Facebook.

In your Facebook app Dashboard go to `Products > Instagram > Basic Display` and should see the ***Instagram App ID***.

Use that in your authorization URL and it should work.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution for this? I’m having the same problem.

Comment: I am using the Instagram app ID and it is still giving this error.

Comment: Same here. I noticed that whatever parameters you put on [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/] , **it will throw an error!** Maybe a bad endpoint? 
In any case, I have followed everything step by step mentioned on [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started] and all worked perfectly fine until **Step 5: Exchange the Code for a Token** where I then use postman to call [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/] with parameters **client_id, client_secret, grant_type, redirect_uri and code (retrieved after successful authorization)**. but fails

Comment: I had the same problem I made the test with postman with passing the parameters through the body and setting x-www-form-urlencoded, it worked like a cham

Comment: The solution of converting the request to an encoded string by @MichaeldeMenten was required for my setup to work. For my use case, that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I have same problem , i use the Instagram App ID

Comment: Hi @Filipe, I have the same problem. I used the appID, but it shows the same error.
And I can't find out `Instagram` on `Products` page. Would you like to show me the screenshot, please?

Answer (score 14):

Passing parameters through the body and in x-www-form-urlencoded works fine as you can see in the picture below [image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by setting the content type of the request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. below is a c# example showing how to execute the request:

```
public async Task<UserTokenResponseModel> GetUserToken(string code)
    {
        var url =
            $"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        var requestContent = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        requestContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId));
        requestContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Secret));
        requestContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        requestContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code));
        requestContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44315/instagram/authorizecallback"));

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestContent);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception(content);
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenResponseModel>(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer as well, problem was with the form body which is supposed to be send in **x-www-form-urlencoded** format. It was working fine for me in postman but to implement the same in **angular** is slightly typical.
Here the post request body first has to converted in the HttpParams format and then pass on to the 'body ' parameter of post request as string like this..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class appService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getInstaAccessToken(formData) {
    let full_url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    let body = new HttpParams()
      .set("client_id" , "YOUR_CLIENT_ID")
      .set("client_secret","YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET")
      .set("code","code received from redirect url")
      .set("grant_type","authorization_code")
      .set("redirect_uri","your redirect uri")
    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    }
    return this.http.post(full_url, body.toString(), requestOptions).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      /* 
        {
          "access_token": "IGQVJ...",
          "user_id": 17841405793187218
        }
      */
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error with Instagram Basic Display API then this answer is for you.

> Problem was I was using the Facebook App ID and App Secret instead of the Instagram App ID & App Secret. You must go to the "Instagram Basic Display" section on the Facebook developer's site then scroll down until you find the Instagram App ID & Secret.