# OAuthException using Instagram Display API

Tags: rest, https, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Getting an error when calling a POST at this endoint. `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize`

This is the request body:

```
{
    "client_id": "62022....13674",
    "client_secret": "081f5d8d8d0.....cfbe88d8df1bf1",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "https://mystifying-khorana-f72562.netlify.com/",
    "code": "AQA6nvV5uJ1PEblnIy2lEx0e6IMc6rOAmnW0Rx6_nVHwQn1IYUp85hRd2rbB9K-BC0877g5Djhy9QjqqD-ImRFPwz0HJDgNEOwD4w5qltzNGYQyoFQd7ttyS9E1E61JdsFduGLXzTU2b8X8vICd_KaJDXeFL9drc8uickz3yy-UaziuKLbExqcMfeEubRcwVnPQFwyLQUnQgcljgXyvV5eeGADgVZYXvZ7Lb7REtyOXReA"
}
```

This is the error that gets returned:

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid platform app"
}
```

It may be something simple but I cannot figure out what is wrong. I followed the getting started piece line by line.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You are `POST`ing to the wrong URL. You need to send that request to: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` to exchange the code for an access token.

Comment: it's not that easy. that does not help either.

Comment: Maybe providing a bit more details about what you are struggling with would help @DingDong

Comment: Sure. You may check my comment here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488911/authenticate-the-test-user-error-type-oauthexception-code-400-error] @hermanschutte

Comment: Seems solved, I guess. x-www-form-urlencoded inside Body request was to be chosen. More here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488911/authenticate-the-test-user-error-type-oauthexception-code-400-error] @hermanschutte