# Instagram API giving "Invalid platform app" error when I am trying to fetch the access token

Tags: objective-c, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to fetch the access token using this API: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token. I have made sure to use the instagram app ID only and have also taken care of the content type to be "x-www-form-urlencoded" as suggested in the following answers: [Authenticate the Test User { "error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app" }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488911/authenticate-the-test-user-error-type-oauthexception-code-400-error). The API works perfectly fine in postman though but gives the following error response through my code:

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app"}

Here is my peice of code:

```
-(void)fetchAccessTokenForInsta{

NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSDictionary *tmp = @{@"client_id":@"126.....", @"client_secret":@"c79c.....", @"grant_type":@"authorization_code", @"redirect_uri":@"https://firebase.google.com/", @"code":_codeStr};
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {

      NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", responseStr);
}] resume];
}
```

Where _codeStr is the string after removing # from the code received in the earlier step. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I was sending parameters in a wrong way. In my case I was omitting querystring.stringify the data object , where I have all the parameters.

Answer (score -2):

The only solution that worked so far is that you ask your server or backend team to develop an API for you that fetches the access token using the instagram API and gives it to you as a response.